# I keep getting the error " The type...has no constructors defined " for the below code

Tags: c#, constructor

I keep getting the error " The type...has no constructors defined " for the below code

```
Application app = new Application();
Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\testcsv.csv", Type.Missing, 
                     Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
                     Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
                     Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

wb.SaveAs(@"C:\testcsv.xlsx", XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook, Type.Missing, 
          Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,  XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, 
          Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

wb.Close();
app.Quit();
```

Im trying to save a csv file as xls.

Answer (score 0):

You have "new Application()" thats a bit vague, you may want to try  "`Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();`" as there are other types of Application and chances are your code is getting very confused.

Comment: Thanks worked like a charm, but now i get an error at workbook saying "namespace could not be found"

Comment: Because Workbook is vauge too.. you may need Excel.Workbook ... or you can change your using statement

Comment: the declared "app" shows error that "a field initializer cannot reference non static field "and "wb" says "its a field but used as type ".

Comment: How did you do your using statement? as your code worked with a couple of changes for me..

Comment: i havnt used a "using" statement..but where should it b used?

Comment: Seriously? you need to read up on this, not just copy and paste someone elses crap then

Comment: But you've not followed simple basic principles such as getting the using statement so it knows what you're talking about...

Comment: could u share ur solution?